# Make footer DIV stay bottom after AJAX content load

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm having problems making the footer DIV move to the bottom of the page after inserting content into the above DIV using AJAX.
So initially when page loads the footer DIV is at bottom page page, but after the AJAX inserts lots of content into the above DIV, the footer just stays there and does not update itself and moves to the bottom.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I'm using jQUERY to insert AJAX content after  page onload.

I already tried using position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0 on the footer div, but still stays there after AJAX call.

Thanks in advance.

```
<body style="width:100%; height:100%;" onload="displayContent()">
    <div id="main" style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
        <div id="header" style="width:100%; height:10%;">
            <div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                <div  style="display:inline; float:left; width:10%; height:100%;">Logo</div>
                <div  style=" display:inline; float:right; width:90%; height:100%;">Navigation Links</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:5%;">
            Navigation links go here
        </div>
        <div id="body" style="width:100%; height:75%;">
            <div id="content" style="display:inline; float:left; width:70%; height:100%;">Main content from AJAX call after page onload goes here</div>
            <div  style="display:inline; float:right; width:30%; height:100%; background:red;">Other stuff here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="width:100%; height:10%;">
            FOOTER NEEDS TO UPDATE ITSELF AFTER AJAX CALL
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the percentage heights you've set to the elements. You need to either give the #body element an auto height, or make it respond to content changes using overflow property.

**I'm not encouraging the use of inline styles**

```html
<body style="width:100%; height:100%;" onload="displayContent()">
    <div id="main" style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
        <div id="header" style="width:100%; height:10%;">
            <div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                <div  style="display:inline; float:left; width:10%; height:100%;">Logo</div>
                <div  style=" display:inline; float:right; width:90%; height:100%;">Navigation Links</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:5%;">
            Navigation links go here
        </div>
        <div id="body" style="width:100%; height:auto; overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="content" style="display:inline; float:left; width:70%; height:100%;">Main content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes hereMain content from AJAX call after page onload goes here</div>
            <div  style="display:inline; float:right; width:30%; height:100%; background:red;">Other stuff here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="width:100%; height:10%;">
            FOOTER NEEDS TO UPDATE ITSELF AFTER AJAX CALL
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

using position: static; bottom:0; you can always force your element to stay at bottom of screen. add bottom-padding to your content-container so that your footer will not be overlapping contents.